# REST, OAuth, and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, oauth

I'm looking for some sort of happy marriage between OAuth 2, REST and Wordpress.

What I HAVE found so far includes:

- **WP-RESTful** plug-in. I might get some ideas from it but it's too basic. Basically just allows using REST URL's to perform Wordpress functions cross-site. Also no OAuth.
- **Restler** GIT source (PHP). Looks really elegant in implementation and would like to use this in a substantial way but doesn't have OAuth nor does it know about Wordpress.
- **Light PHP Wrapper for OAuth 2** on GIT (https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2.git). Looks like a good starting point; don't know how to compare it yet to below ...
- **Fuel OAuth 2** on GIT (https://github.com/fuel-packages/fuel-oauth2.git). Also looks really good and has recent activity which I always view positively. :^)

Anyway, what I'm really dreaming about is an integrated solution that combines everything. In the abscence of this beautiful dream I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions any of the individual components (would need to be PHP-based code).